# Check if an array contain multiple values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
[
  {
    _id: "646231c54574e0e7ffc569e9",
    users: [
      {
        _id: "6461ef44496eff14402778af",
        name: "Salman Khan"
      },
      {
        _id: "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0",
        name: "Yash Sharma"
      {
        _id: "646211fac7359b7ed8f27bcb",
        name: "abcd",
    ]
  }
]
```

I have an array with items like the above one. Now, I want to get that element which containes two specific `_id` in it's `users` array.

Comment: `mainarr.filter(x => x.users.length === 2)`?

Comment: I don't need to check length. I need to check if two ```id``` for example ```id: xxx``` and ```id: yyy``` are present in the ```users``` array of an element or not.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: @David ```element.find(elm => elm.users.map(item => item._id) === [id1, id2])```. Tried this. Didn't work. Returned undefined.

Comment: element.find and inisde create a set of users id. `const a = new Set(elm.users.map(item => item._id))` and then `return [id1, id2].every(e => a.has(e))`

Comment: @YashSharma: The first point is that `===` isn't how you compare the contents of two arrays, but that logic brings up another point... Are you looking for elements which *have* those ID values, or which ***only** have* those ID values?  Your attempt implies the latter.  So, for example, the (broken) data structure shown shouldn't match because it has three IDs and the code is specifically looking for two specific IDs and *only* those two specific IDs.  Is that the intent?

Comment: @David I'm looking for elements which only have two values not any other value.

Answer (score 1):

Start by semantically describing what you're trying to accomplish:

> Array elements where:
>
> - the `users` array contains an element with an `_id` of X and,
> - the `users` array contains an element with an `_id` of Y and,
> - the `users` array contains no other elements

*Third condition added based on [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314239/check-if-an-array-contain-multiple-values-javascript?noredirect=1#comment134573411_76314239): "I'm looking for elements which only have two values not any other value."*

The description essentially defines the logic.  For example:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    _id: "this one matches",
    users: [
      {
        _id: "6461ef44496eff14402778af",
        name: "Salman Khan"
      },
      {
        _id: "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0",
        name: "Yash Sharma"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "this one does not",
    users: [
      {
        _id: "6461ef44496eff14402778af",
        name: "Salman Khan"
      },
      {
        _id: "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0",
        name: "Yash Sharma"
      },
      {
        _id: "646211fac7359b7ed8f27bcb",
        name: "abcd",
      }
    ]
  }
];

const matches = arr.filter(a => 
  a.users.find(x => x._id === "6461ef44496eff14402778af") && // check for one ID
  a.users.find(x => x._id === "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0") && // check for another ID
  a.users.length === 2 // make sure it has only those IDs (assuming they're unique)
);

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method in combination with every element which will loop through your in put array and check if that is exists in each of the users array.

```
const elements = [
  {
    _id: "646231c54574e0e7ffc569e9",
    users: [
      {
        _id: "6461ef44496eff14402778af",
        name: "Salman Khan"
      },
      {
        _id: "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0",
        name: "Yash Sharma"
        },
      {
        _id: "646211fac7359b7ed8f27bcb",
        name: "abcd"
        }
    ]
  }
];

const ids = ["6461ef44496eff14402778af", "6461f15bb4e0a6c7addc9fb0"];
const result = elements.filter(elem => {
    return ids.every(id => elem.users.findIndex(e => e._id === id) > -1);
});
console.log(result);
```